# experimentalDecorators error in typegrapql

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I am currently learning TypeGraphQL and trying to create a basic reslover, my code looks like this:

```
@Resolver()
class HelloReslover {
    @Query(() => String)

    async hello(){
        return "hello wtold"
    }
}
```

But i got this error:

> "Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to
> change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in
> your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning."

But my `tsconfig` file looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "declaration": false,
  
      "composite": false,
      "removeComments": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "strictFunctionTypes": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "rootDir": "src"
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Strange, can you share the code?

Comment: i fixed it on my own , i will share how in case that anyone faces the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it on my own , here how is I did it:

I deleted everything in `tsconfig.json` and replaced it whit this code:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2018", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```